# Conditionally use existing attribute

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, attributes

I have an ASP.NET Core WebApi that has a few controllers which should not be deployed for one if its versions. Currently, I'm using the [NonController] attribute which I'm commenting out when said controllers should be deployed.

Is there a way to conditionally return [NonController] using a custom attribute (or some other way)?

Thanks

Comment: Not clear about your question, the  `[NonController]` is used to explain the class is not an MVC controller.

Comment: Please add some code of what you are trying to achieve